# Is there a way to retrieve disk space of individual directories using Prometheus node exporter

Tags: directory, prometheus, diskspace, prometheus-node-exporter

Is there a way to retrieve disk space of individual directories using Prometheus node exporter?.

I see only we can give mount points to fetch used/available disk space data.

`100 - ((node_filesystem_avail_bytes{instance="<instance>:9100",job="prometheus",mountpoint='/mount/pointName'} * 100) / node_filesystem_size_bytes{instance="<instance>:9100",job="prometheus",mountpoint='mount/pointName'})`

Anyway we can get disk space consumption details of say all top level directories under a mount point?.

If not instead of using `mountpoint` any similar way we can loop through or show `tree` / `directory` level details say in `GB` consumed & available?

Comment: got any alternative solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Textfile Collector to monitor directory sizes:
https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#textfile-collector

For example you could have a cronjob that runs the `du` command against different directory sizes, use `sed` to format the output, and then redirect it to a file at a specific path.

Configure the `--collector.textfile.directory` node_exporter flag to read from the directory the file is in.

When the node exporter is scraped by Prometheus, it will also read the file and make the samples available to be graphed, with the directories as `labels`